# Friendly URL using httpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

well, I can try to work with friendy Url in my application but I'm having some dificulty with wht friendly using httpModule.

My web site, in the localhost, don't have problem, but when I try to run in the server occurs problem only my url have queryString, for exemplo:

mysite/articles+88+title => mysite/articles.asxp?cd=88 = problem

mysite/donwload => mysite/dos_as.aspx = no problem

Grateful for the help.

Comment: Where have you defined the URL rewriting?

Comment: A created a httpModule and a defined url rewriting in context_BeginRequest...
I tried to put in the global.asax but ocurrs the same problem

Comment: Are you on webforms or mvc?

Comment: I use webforms, the server was running the iis7 but exists other server that use iis6

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Is it iis7 or iis6?

Comment: both, cause have 2 servers, but I was testing in the 7.

Comment: Your URLs are a bit strange.  Query strings are supposed to be something like this `mysite/articles?id=88&title=mytitle` not `mysite/articles+88+title`.

Comment: my URLs are mysite/articles?id=88&title=mytitle and my friendly URLs mysite/articles+88+title

Comment: You're saying your code works locally on IIS7 but not remotely on IIS6?

Comment: No, remotely on IIS7 and locally not using IIS (using ASPNET Development server). Do you undestand?

Comment: Even locally, you would still be using IIS.  Try installing this extension for IIS http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite there is a video that should teach you how.  You would also have to do this on your IIS server remotely.

Comment: I found a soluction. I implemented my friendly URLs using "/", for example mysite/articles/88/title, and used the HTML tag <base> in my pages. Trank's for your attention!